# unsigned char concatenation

Tags: c++, char, concatenation, unsigned

I am creating a C++ program for communication with a gripper on a serial port.

I have to send a buffer of type "unsigned char [8]", but of these 8 bytes, 4 are entered from the keyboard, and 2 are the CRC, calculated at the time.

So, how can I concatenate several pieces in a single buffer of 8 bytes unsigned char?

For example:

```
unsigned char buffer[8];
----
unsigned char DLEN[1]={0x05};
----
unsigned char CMD[1]={0x01};
----
unsigned char data[4]={0x00,0x01,0x20,0x41};
----
unsigned char CRC[2]={0xFF,0x41};
----
```

how can I get this buffer:  `{0x05,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x20,0x41,0xFF,0x41}`  that is the union of `DLEN`,`CMD`,`data` and `CRC`?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
buffer[0] = DLEN[0];
buffer[1] = CMD[0];
buffer[2] = data[0];
buffer[3] = data[1];
buffer[4] = data[2];
buffer[5] = data[3];
buffer[6] = CRC[0];
buffer[7] = CRC[1];
```

Comment: Or `buffer[0] = DLEN[0]; buffer[1] = CMD[0]; std::copy(begin(data),end(data),buffer+sizeof DLEN+sizeof CMD); std::copy(begin(CRC),end(CRC),buffer+sizeof DLEN+sizeof CMD+sizeof data);` (broken up onto separate lines, of course)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is this:

Start off with an unsigned char array of 8 characters.

When you need to pass it off to other methods to have data inserted in them, pass it by reference like this: `updateCRC(&buffer[6])` with the method signature taking an unsigned char pointer.  Assuming you respect the respective sizes of the inputs, the result is the best of both worlds, handling the buffer as if they were separate strings, and not having to merge it into a single array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bit shifting, the `<<` and `>>` operators, to get the appropriate fields to the right places in the buffer.

Something like `buffer |= (DLEN << 7);`

Just make sure your buffer is cleared to be all 0's first.

Comment: This won't work. All the types are arrays of chars. You can't bit shift an array.

Answer (score 0):

My version of hmjd's answer:

```
buffer[0] = DLEN[0];
buffer[1] = CMD[0];
std::copy(begin(data),end(data),buffer+sizeof DLEN+sizeof CMD);
std::copy(begin(CRC) ,end(CRC) ,buffer+sizeof DLEN+sizeof CMD+sizeof data);
```